# Property of zeros of a bounded non-constant, holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, roots, holomorphic-functions

I need help with the following problem:

> Let $f: B_1(0) \to \mathbb C$, where $B_1(0)$ denotes the unit disk, be a holomorphic, bounded and non-constant function with zeros $(z_k)_{k\in \mathbb N}$ (in particular, $\lvert z_k \rvert < 1$ for all $k\in \mathbb N$. Prove:
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-\lvert z_k \rvert) < \infty$$
>   Hint: Use Jensen's formula.

My thoughts:
Obviously, we need $\lvert z_k \rvert \to 1$ for that sum to converge.
This is already were I struggle. Why does every function of this type have infinitely many zeros near $|z|=1$ and impossibly at any other arbitrary value $|z| < 1$? I don't really have a good intuition here. Also this is required to use Jensen's formula.
The other thing I tried to show is $f(0) \neq 0$. Why is that? I don't see why it shouldn't be possible to have a function with the given properties and with $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: Let $F(z) = f(z) z^{-n}$ such that $F(0) \ne 0$. If $\forall k,|z_k| \ne r$ then Jensen's formula says $$ \log |F(0)| = \sum_{|z_k|< r} \log \left( \frac{|z_k|}{r}\right) + \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \log|F(re^{i\theta})| \, d\theta$$ The result is obtained as $r \to 1^-$

Comment: Why is $F(0) \neq 0$? It is undefined at $z = 0$ as far as I can see. Also, how does the result follow from $r \to 1^-$?

Comment: Come on.. If $f(z)$ has a zero of order $n$ at $z=0$ set $F(z) = f(z) z^{-n}$ which is holomorphic and non-zero at $z=0$.

Comment: Okay, you mean $f(z)z^{-n}$ has a holomorphic continuation at $z = 0$. Now I get it. But I still can't see how the result follows when $r\to 0^-$.

Comment: In complex analysis $\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ is well-defined holomorphic at $z=0$, we always consider continuous and analytic continuation of functions when it is possible

Comment: Since $\log(1+a) \sim a$ : $\sum_k \log(|z_k|)$ converges iff $\sum_k (1-|z_k|)$ converges

Comment: I see. I will think about it. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how to show $\lim_{r \to 1^-}\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \log|F(re^{i\theta})| \, d\theta$ converges. It must follow from $f$ being bounded.

Answer (score 1):

By hypothesis, there are infinitely many $z_i$.
You can arrange them so that $|z_1|\le|z_2|\le\cdots$.
If $|z_n|\not\to 1$ then $|z_n|\to a<1$. The closed disc
$\overline{B_a(0)}$ would have infinitely many zeros of $f$,
which is impossible by a compactness argument. So $|z_n|\to1$.

Jensen's formula usually assumes $f(0)\ne0$, but if $f(0)=0$
write $f(z)=z^k g(z)$ with $g(0)=0$ and apply it to $g$ instead.

Comment: How do you show $\lim_{r \to 1^-}\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \log|g(re^{i\theta})| \, d\theta$ converges ?

Comment: @Lord You mean $f(0)\neq 0$ in the first appearance (and for g).